# How do you append string to each item in an array list

Tags: c#

Items should be displayed,separated by comma after country code appended,like 44904223322,44504905949,44304940393

```
 HashSet<string> phonearr = new HashSet<string>();
 conn.Open();
 MySqlCommand sda = new MySqlCommand("select * from members where Branch='" + lbladminbranch.Text + "' and Country='" + lbladmincountry.Text + "'", conn);

 MySqlDataReader dr = sda.ExecuteReader();

 while (dr.Read())
 {
   StringBuilder countrycode = new StringBuilder("44");
   phonearr.Add(dr["Phone"].ToString());

   foreach(string phone in phonearr)
   {
    countrycode.Append(phone);
   }

   txtsmsphoneno.Text = string.Join(",",countrycode );
  }
   conn.Close();
```

Comment: Can you explain what `string.Join(",",countrycode )` supposed to do?

Comment: its separates each phone number with a comma ,eg. 06340404304,0434040344,055344343443

Comment: ??? `countrycode` is `StringBuilder` - I don't understand why you think that code does insert commas insider `StringBuilder`...

Comment: it was a mistake and i needed solution ,and solution was given below

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten your code and just add the "44" when adding to the phonearr (changed to phoneList here).

```
 List<string> phoneList = new List<string>();
 conn.Open();
 MySqlCommand sda = new MySqlCommand("select * from members where Branch='" + lbladminbranch.Text + "' and Country='" + lbladmincountry.Text + "'", conn);

 MySqlDataReader dr = sda.ExecuteReader();

 while (dr.Read())
 {
    phoneList.Add("44" + dr["Phone"].ToString());
 }
 txtsmsphoneno.Text = string.Join(",",phoneList);
 conn.Close();
```